# python recv from closed blocking socket

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to write a tcp socket based server. In python documentation I read, that `recv` on closed socket should raise error. But when a client closes the socket, the server can still `recv` on this socket and gets empty string. Can I assume then, that if `recv` returns empty string on a blocking socket, that this connection broke or was closed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if you have received data from the client. If the data variable is empty, you can assume that there isn't a connection, because the client has closed the socket or something was wrong between them. Good examples are in https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example or if you are using python3: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html#example

Answer (score -1):

You must handle IOError exceptions by codes.

```
except IOError as io_error:
    if io_error.errno == <YOUR CODE>:
        do something
```

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html#module-errno
for get codes

Comment: But when client program crashes or when the client unexpectedly closes socket, without any warning it doesn't raise any exceptions. `recv` then returns empty string on a blocking socket.

Comment: Show your case. Simple client and server, please. I can't understand what do you mean

Comment: Yeah, I have this already in my app. The question is, if I can safely assume, that this will work every time. I thought, that `recv` in this situation will crash, so I'm a bit confused right now.

Comment: You can handle exception IOError and other in try .. except. All exceptions of IOError can ignore.